# react-select add a search input inside the MenuList

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm using react-select (https://react-select.com) and I'm trying to add a search input inside the MenuList itself (at the top) instead of the default behaviour of searching from the Container.

```
<Select
   ...
   components={{
      ...
      MenuList: (props: any) => {
         return (
            <components.MenuList {...props}>
               <div className="search-wrapper">
                  <input 
                     value={search}
                     onChange={searchChange}
                     placeholder="Search"/>
                </div>
                {props.children}
             </components.MenuList>
          );
       },
   }}
>
</Select>
```

It's working and I get a nice input in the top of my menu:

[image]

but the input seems to be disabled. (adding disabled=false to the input doesn't effect anything)

any idea of that? why it's happens?
what is the correct way to implement such feature?

Comment: might be you implemented it wrong, I use it and is working fine

Comment: @AkhilAravind any idea what I did wrong? :)

Comment: Have you tried to look at the library's author example here ? https://react-select.com/advanced#experimental

Comment: Yes @Laura Thank you. In this example they use some trick to wrap the select with dropdown so the select is the menu itself. Hoped I would find a way without reaching that kind of solution.

Comment: Could you add your entire code with the CSS ? Thank you

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? Or could you share an example @AkhilAravind?

Comment: @tamj0rd2 I used it long before, works clean. I think the demo in the doc itself is good and clean example

Comment: Which example @AkhilAravind? I want to put a different input inside of the MenuList, but when I do, it's not possible to focus it/enter text. I have the same use case as the OP. I don't think any of the experimental examples apply here, unless I'm looking at the wrong thing

Comment: I found nice example in https://codesandbox.io/embed/m75wlyx3oy. 
(Not my solution)

Answer (score 0):

This variant works for me.

First you should remove `innerProps` prop from `components.Menu`.
I didn't try with `components.MenuList`, but I guess it should works too.

`<components.MenuList {...props} innerProps={undefined}>`

Then you will be able to use input, but menu will close on every click, so:
Second you should control menu state with `menuIsOpen` prop.
first you can override SelectContainer:

```js
const SelectContainer: React.FC<CommonProps<object, false>> = ({ children, ...props }) => (
  <components.SelectContainer {...props}>
    <div onClick={() => setMenuOpen(true)}>
      {children}
    </div>
  </components.SelectContainer>
);
```

Then add a handler to close menu on click inside menu.